# iOS: How to determine which iOS devices your app can be deployed on

Tags: ios, xcode

Some basic questions about iOS versioning:

1. We're now using Xcode 8 with Swift 3.  Does this mean our app can only run on devices with iOS 10?
2. If you have a dependency on an iOS version how does Apple prevent someone from installing it on a device with the wrong iOS version?
3. How do you control which devices (iOS version, iPhone vs iPad) your app is targeted for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No. Minimal iOS version is not affected by Xcode version nor used language. You can set it as `Deployment target` in project settings:

[image]

*Note, that you won't be able to develop for iOS 10 on old versions of Xcode.*

2. A deployed app is just not available in the AppStore if iOS version of the device is not supported by the app.
3. Minimal iOS version is set as Deployment Target (see p.1). You can also specify Base SDK in `Build Settings` (image below), which allows you to use the latest features available. But even if you ship for iOS 9, app will usually launch on devices with iOS 10, but it may be unstable until you adopt the code for the latest SDK.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I will add to answer of @alexburtnik. He is right you can set your deployment target to set which devices can use it.

-> Go to Target of your app

-> Go to deployment info

-> Pick Deployment Target (This is iOS Version)

-> Pick Devices  (iPhone,iPad & Universal)

Screen shots

[For Device Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDNCD.png)

[For iOS version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCY6X.png)

You might have gotten confused because XCode 8 default recommended os version is iOS 10. You can pick lower version which will work on anything above that version (like pick 8 will work on devices 8-9-10 iOS). But pick carefully as couple of new cool APIs will not be available on older versions. You will have to code considering newer and older version and code might end up having if-else version ladder which will make it really messy to maintain code.

I had similar experience with UIAlertView and UIAlertController. As older versions do not support UIAlertController but it has couple of cool features which can come handy while working with newer version.

Hope this helps. :)